# mod_security 2.6 + mod_fcgid not working

Tags: freebsd, apache-http-server, php-cli

I have installed:

- Apache 2.2 + suexec (libxml2, etc.)
- Mod_security 2.6
- Mod_fcgid

I am using APACHE with newest hybrid EVENT MPM. I think it can be related to the problem.

Here is the problem:

Mod_security detects a threat, but do not blocks. Here is a message from audit log:

```
Message: Access denied with code 403 (phase 4). Pattern match "asdasdasd" at REQUEST_URI. [file "/usr/local/etc/apache22/httpd.conf"] [line "533"] [msg "Access Denied"]
Action: Intercepted (phase 4)
```

It looks like the client was blocked with exit code 403 - **BUT IT WAS NOT!**

I tried requesting .html file, for example url with MY MATCH KEYWORD /asdasdasd.html - mod_security has blocked the url as it supposed.

**So mod_security does not work with .php files only.**

Do you know how to solve the problem ? Thanks!